# How do I read and verify if there are images that are on my PHP server but by HTTPS?

Tags: php, image, web-services, https, subdomain

I want to check my images on my server, and I have another subdomain to save the images but they are served with HTTPS

It only works locally, but not remotely by HTTPS, as it always prints "exists directory".

```
$foto = "https://subdomain.example.com/images/" . $var . "/" . $var2. "/flayer";

if (file_exists($foto . ".jpg")) {
    echo "HELLO WORL";
}

if (glob($foto . ".*")) {
    if (file_exists($foto . ".jpg")) {
        $ruta = "https://subdomain.example.com/images/". $var . "/" . $var2 . "/flayer.jpg";
    }else{ 
        echo "no exists";
    }
}else{
    echo "no exists on directory";
}
```

Comment: I'd say your webserver has a ssl configuration issue. You're also not providing any errors or log messages that might indicate what is failing.

Comment: `always print "exists directory".` - you code doesn't show that?

Comment: `glob()` can't be used on URLs.

Comment: @Jaquarh I'm guessing he mistyped and meant it always prints `no exists on directory`

Comment: The HTTP protocol doesn't have any way to list a directory or match a wildcard. You can't use `glob()`, you can only test for specific filenames.

Comment: the glob () is not necessary, I deleted it, I will only use the file_exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i test with 2 options

```
   function remote_file_exists($url, $ext) {
    $ch = curl_init($url . $ext);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($httpCode == 200) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

AND

```
    function remote($url, $ext) {
    if (@exif_imagetype($url . $ext)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Works but is so slow, something to do it more fast?

Comment: i sent remote ("https://subdomain.domain.com/images/flayer",".jpg") and works but is slow to response.

Answer (score 0):

`glob()` is a directory service. If it is a sub directory of your domain, then your file system should be stored on the same server. Inside your index folder, define or store a variable to this path - treat it like an enviromental variable.

```
define('PUBLIC_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

You can now loop through your directory at your sub domain. It will be a folder named what your sub domain is called.

```
foreach(glob(PUBLIC_ROOT . '/subdomain/images/*.jpg', GLOB_BRACE) as $image)
    // Do something with each JPEG image
```

If for some reason, your sub domain is hosted else where - strange - or it is an external site and you **need** to use HTTP. Send a `cURL` request. You can specify nobody in the header.

```
$ch = curl_init('https://sub.example.com/images/foo.jpg');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec  ($ch);

if(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) != 200)
    // It didn't exist

curl_close($ch);
```

You cannot use a directory service (DS protocols) cross domain (over HTTP protocols).

> **Moving on point:** If you need a collection of all of the images held on that server, then consider building an API that returns a JSON encoded array of all of the file paths or dynamic URI's on your sub domain, then request it from another domain.

Comment: Hi, y delete glob() is not necesary, but not works, my images are in one directory on my subdomain, I enter a folder and then I look for a specific image, so the variables of step, it still does not work, could you please explain? Thank you

Comment: To cut it simple, you can’t use glob over HTTP.